# What do I need to install to make sharp work?

Tags: debian, node.js

I need to deploy an API made with Node.js, this API uses the [sharp package](http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/). I'm using a Linux server running Debian 9 but I need to install some packages in Debian to make it work.

I already installed node.js, gcc, make, phyton 2.7 and node-gyp but the package doesn't work yet.

I get a lot of errors when I run `npm install` when the sharp package is download.

```
> sharp@0.20.5 install /home/desarrollador/my-api/node_modules/sharp
> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)

info sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.6.1/libvips-8.6.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=11.12.0 runtime=node arch=x64 platform=linux)
make: Entering directory '/home/desarrollador/my-api/node_modules/sharp/build'
```

I think it's a problem with `node-gyp`.

Comment: Have you installed Node.js?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't list node.js.